How do I correctly use the ternary operator ( : ? ) in a Razor template?
I'm building a custom mega menu that be used for a Sitefinity site. I'm still learning C# and Razor so excuse any errors in my code methods. I'm using bootstrap to do most of the heavy lifting CSS wise. In my code you can see I'm trying to use the ternary operator to check if there are items listed for a sub menu to be populated. If yes then add the class dropdown if not add a blank space or leave it blank so that the class isn't added. I also use the ternary operator to check and see if there is a mega menu selected in the back of the site. Which adds the class has-megamenu. I'm getting the following error in the browser:
error CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Web.IHtmlString' and 'string'

@* code omitted... *@
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto flex-nowrap">
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    string linkClass = "nav-link";
    string toggleAttribute = "";
    string inlineEditingAttribute = "";

    var navigateUrl = HyperLinkHelpers.GetDetailPageUrl(item, ViewBag.DetailsPageId, ViewBag.OpenInSamePage, Model.UrlKeyPrefix);
    var subMenuItems = item.Fields.SubMenuItems as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
    bool hasSubMenuItems = subMenuItems != null && subMenuItems.Any();
    var relatedSubMenuItems = item.Fields.RelatedSubMenuItems as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
    bool hasRelatedSubMenuItems = relatedSubMenuItems != null && relatedSubMenuItems.Any();
    bool hasMegaMenu = hasSubMenuItems && subMenuItems.Any(subItem => subItem.MegaMenuSelection.ToHtmlString() ==  @Html.Raw("Yes"));

    if (hasSubMenuItems)
    {
        linkClass += " dropdown-toggle";
        toggleAttribute = "dropdown";
        inlineEditingAttribute = Html.InlineEditingFieldAttributes("Title", "ShortText").ToHtmlString();
    }

    <li class="nav-item 
    @(hasSubMenuItems ? "dropdown" : @Html.Raw("&nbsp;")) 
    @(hasMegaMenu ? "has-megamenu" : @Html.Raw("&nbsp;"))" 
    @Html.InlineEditingAttributes(Model.ProviderName, Model.ContentType.FullName, (Guid)item.Fields.Id)>

    <a 
        class="@linkClass" 
        data-bs-toggle="@toggleAttribute" 
        href="@navigateUrl" 
        @Html.Raw(inlineEditingAttribute)>
        @item.Fields.Title
    </a>

    @* code omitted... *@
    </li>
}
</ul>
@* code omitted... *@

I have tired different variations of this code. I can get this to show the main navigation items and the drop downs. But, when I add in the code to check if a navigation item has a drop down or mega menu. It's seems simple enough to figure out. But, this has me stomped.

Hi @Aaron Jackson please take a look if my answer helps. Are you using Blazor?

Html.Raw returns IHtmlString, an interface to delay writing the result to the output stream. Not sure why you're trying to include "&nbsp;" as a css class name. Just use ? "something" : null instead.

Allow me to remove most of your code to demonstrate the minimal way to do it if all you want is to conditionally setting css class. Please note it works on Blazor but I am not sure if you are working with traditional razor page.
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto flex-nowrap">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <li class="@GetCssClass(item)" 
        @Html.InlineEditingAttributes(Model.ProviderName, Model.ContentType.FullName, (Guid)item.Fields.Id)>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
@code 
{
    public string GetCssClass(Item item)
    {
        var subMenuItems = item.Fields.SubMenuItems as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
        bool hasSubMenuItems = subMenuItems != null && subMenuItems.Any();
        var cssClass = hasSubMenuItems ? " dropdown" : string.Empty;
        return $"nav-item{cssClass}";
    }
}

You write a method and then use it directly in setting the class attribute.

Thanks for helping out. So I'm not sure if this is using Blazor or not. I'm building this inside of Sitefinity. I'm using the custom web builder to create the custom fields and a custom widget template to access the data. So that @Html.InlineEditingAttribute(ect).. is all code that Sitefinity adds in the beginning. I just didn't take it out yet. Apologies for the late reply here. I was pulled off this project for a bit. But, I'm back on now.
